# Obtaining Button From Another Layout (ViewPager)?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm working on an application and the requirements specify that two ViewPagers interact separately. My problem is, the bottom ViewPager has to contain buttons that move with the ViewPager when swiped. That being said, I can not obtain the buttons needed within the main activity because the axml layout of the current view only contains the two viewpagers which are then set programmatically.

Here's the AXML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/mainViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/bottomViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#998822">
<Button
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:id="@+id/menu_button"
    android:text="Menu"
    android:textSize="12dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Here's how I would like to capture the button:

```
m_MenuButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menu_button);
```

So my question is: What is the best course of action to provide both on-click functionality while also maintaining the button's relationship with the view pager (aka, sliding when it slides)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this at work and what I did was have a separate xml of each tile of the pageview, so move your button in to a fragment.

then get the second PageViewer to display fragments as tiles.

then the constructor for the 'tile' fragments you can pass in the class in which you want call a method from when your button is pressed.

so your base page should look like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/mainViewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/bottomViewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

then create a second Xml for the fragments (these could be cards, webviews what ever it is you are displaying)
to look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#998822">
<Button
android:layout_width="75dp"
android:layout_height="75dp"
android:id="@+id/menu_button"
android:text="Menu"
android:textSize="12dp" />
```

then create a card Fragment and Change the constuctor to

```
   ...
   // create an instave variable called parent so you can access the other class
 private SomeClassThatHasAMethodYouWantToCall parent;

 static CardFragment newInstance(SomeClassThatHasAMethodYouWantToCall parent) {
        CardFragment cf = new CardFragment();
         this.parent = parent;
        return f;
    }


 // then in onCreateView
   pubklic  View OnCreateView()
{
   View myView = infalter.inflate(containter , R.layout.myCard, false);
   Button b = myView.findViewById(R.id.Mybutton);
   b.setOnClickListener(v -> callMethod()); // shortened for brevity
   return myView;
}

  private void callMethod(){
       parent.callTheMethodYouWantInTheOtherClass();
  }
```

When you implement your pagerAdapter you will  have to override the setPrimar

Comment: I'm not sure why it says avoid comments like "thanks" - but thank you.

Comment: Oh, but I can't seem to access 'parent' in that context.

Comment: Roger that. Thanks again, Brother.

Comment: It is a pattern that works well for me in my last app

Comment: Android studios tells me not to modify the constructor. Is there a way around this? Is it safe?

Comment: Sorry you are right you have to use as static method as above

Comment: Can't use this in a static method but I just replaced this with the object and it worked perfectly. Thank you, very much. I did not even think of taking that route. You're the man.

Answer (score 1):

For Future Reference:

```
public class PanelFragment_One extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView
            (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.panel_fragment_one, container, false);

        final Button menu_button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.menu_button);
        menu_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(PanelFragment_One.super.getContext(),
                        menu_button.getText() + " Clicked!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```